# Тип 'void' не может быть назначен для типа 'protoOffer[] '

Tags: typescript

Возникла проблема с типизацией.
Есть такой код:

```
    const nearbyFilter = (currentCoordinates : Сoordinates, arrayOffers: protoOffer[]): protoOffer[] => {
  const {latitude, longitude} = currentCoordinates;
  const center = L.latLng({lat: latitude , lng: longitude });

  const nearby = arrayOffers.forEach((el) => { //вот на эту константу выдает ошибку(название в заголовке)
    el.coordinates.distance = Math.round(center.distanceTo({lat:el.coordinates.latiti, lng: el.coordinates.lnglng}) / 1000));
});

  return nearby;
}
```

Вопрос, да кто вообще такой этот тип void? Откуда он здесь? Разве не должна константа nearby автоматом становиться protoOffer[]? Если нет, то почему она void.Буду очень благодарен, если вы меня просветите. Спасибо!

Comment: `forEach` ничего не возвращает. поэтому и присваивать результат нет смысла

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!